# How to know if $(8,7,7,6,5,5,4,3,3,2,1,1)$ is a Simple Graph w/o using Havel-Hakimi Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've used the Havel-Hakimi Algorithm to show this sequence $(8,7,7,6,5,5,4,3,3,2,1,1)$ is simple, but is somewhat time consuming for a test.  Is there a way to determine without using algorithms? Or using a faster algorithm?

Comment: Took me about one minute to do it by hand. How fast do you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Havel-Hakimi algorithm.

$8\ 7\ 7\ 6\ 5\ 5\ 4\ 3\ 3\ 2\ 1\ 1$
$\ \ \ 6\ 6\ 5\ 4\ 4\ 3\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 1\ 1$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ 5\ 4\ 3\ 3\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 1\ 1\ 1$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3\ 2\ 2\ 2\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1$

Yes, it's a graphic sequence (the degree sequence of a simple graph).